# 権限 - see votes, expandable usercard - スタック・オーバーフロー のページ内に誤字がある

Tags: バグ, 完了

[権限 - see votes, expandable usercard - スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user)
上記のページ内に誤字があります。

ページ中央付近の見出しが

**拡張ユーザーカードにはどんあ情報が表示されますか?**
となっています。

**どんあ** を **どんな** に訂正してください。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

適用しました。ご確認よろしくお願いします。

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user